# Wrapping wget in python

Tags: python, wget

I am trying to call wget from python and also get wget's downloading progress feedback like this :

```
[ <=>                  ]  10.97K  --.-KB/s    in 0.01s
```

.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import logging
import subprocess
import sys
import inspect

def run_and_printchar(args):
    try:
        pipe = subprocess.Popen(args, bufsize = 0,
            shell = False,
            stdout = None, # no redirection, child use parent's stdout
            stderr = subprocess.PIPE) # redirection stderr, create a new pipe, from which later we will read
    except Exception as e:
        #inspect.stack()[1][3] will get caller function name
        logging.error(inspect.stack()[1][3] + ' error: ' + str(e))
        return False
    while 1:
        #use read(1), can get wget progress bar like output
        s = pipe.stderr.read(1)
        if s:
            sys.stdout.write(s)
            #print(s,end='\r')
            sys.stdout.flush()
        if pipe.returncode is None:

            code = pipe.poll()
        else:
            break
    if not 0 == pipe.returncode:
        return False
    return True



run_and_printchar(["wget","args","go","here"])
```

But instead I get something that looks like this:

```
    0K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  155K 4h37m
    50K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  323K 3h25m
   100K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  359K 2h56m
   150K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  403K 2h39m
   200K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 1023K 2h15m
   250K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  422K 2h10m
   300K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 1.30M 1h56m
   350K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  447K 1h53m
   400K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 1.38M 1h44m
   450K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  447K 1h43m
   500K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 1.79M 96m26s
   550K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  453K 96m19s
   600K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 1.56M 90m59s
   650K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 2.33M 85m46s
   700K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  470K 86m10s
   750K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 1.50M 82m32s
   800K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 2.81M 78m33s
   850K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  469K 79m18s
   900K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 1.92M 76m16s
   950K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0% 2.11M 73m27s
  1000K .......... .......... .......... .......... ..........  0%  512K 73m58s
```

I am using **Python 2.7**

Do you know what may be the problem ?

Comment: You could use `progressbar2` to create a similar thing on your own

Comment: `wget` is checking whether its output is going to a terminal. It only displays the progress as a bar on a terminal.

Comment: @Barmar I really don't understand exactly what you are trying to say? Sorry if I sound ignorant in advance :/

Comment: The `stdout` of `wget` is connected to the pipe that your script is reading from, because of `stderr=PIPE`. Since that's not a terminal, `wget` shows the progress as multiple lines of text instead of a graphical bar on a single line.

Comment: Do you think I should be able to always display one updating line ? I don't have words to explain what I mean. Similar to what '\r' is doing.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68712/how-to-detect-if-a-program-is-not-run-from-a-terminal

Comment: You might find `pexpect` (python module) or `expect` (command line tool / tcl extension) useful.  Also, some googleable terms: tty, pty, isatty